# How Profiler works in JIT Compiler of Execution Engine?

Tags: java

Every time we run Java application by using command "java className", then new jvm instance will be created.
Profiler in execution engine identifies Hotspots meaning repeatedly executing methods and put native code of that hotspots. Now doing so, entire java application will be interpreted at least once and by that time hotspots are identified, so next time if we run java application then those hotspots's native code will be directly taken and will not be interpreted again.
Now my question is if we again run java application then new jvm instance will be created and hotspots were identified in previous jvm. how does it work? Both are different jvm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the main question would be: **is JIT related info (hotspots and compiled code) being retained across JVM restarts?**

**The answer is generally no.** JIT saves all of this information in the Metaspace, all of it gets created at runtime, and then disappears when the JVM stops. It is not persisted anywhere, and when a new JVM starts up again, the JIT optimizations will be redone.

*Why "generally":

Over the past years there were talks about actually saving this information. OpenJDK community was considering to implement it, and there is a paid solution that actually implements this feature as its main selling point:*

[Zing](https://www.azul.com/products/zing/readynow-technology-for-zing/)

Comment: So if we run java application again, then those all information will be gone as new jvm instance will be created, then what is the use of identifying hotspots? How can those hotspots be used again?

Comment: The JVM identifies hotspots, so it knows which code parts need to be compiled into binary. If you would ever want to reuse something from JIT, it would not be the hotspots, but the actual compiled code. But as I wrote above, you cannot reuse them. There are some technologies that attempt to provide a solution like that, but they are not common, not widely used, and in 99.99% of the cases any Java application you encounter will do the JIT at runtime, as its name suggests (Just-In-Time compiler).